# Can I set the width of a textbox to be based on $(window).width() in jQuery?

Tags: jquery

I am having a problem trying to set the width of a textbox. I want to set it to:

```
$(window).width() - 20);
```

Is that possible if my selector is the following:

```
$('#textbox1').
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is that possible if my selector is the following:

It is possible if the `id` of your element is `textbox1`:

```
<input id="textbox1" />
```

In that case, try this:

```
$('#textbox1').width($(window).width() - 20);
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why not:

```
$('#textbox1').width($(window).width() - 20);
```